# Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-functions, ioredis

Encountering ioredis connection timeout when using cloud function in console

Error message below

Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

```
at TLSSocket.\<anonymous\> (/workspace/node_modules/ioredis/built/Redis.js:168:41)

at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)

at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)

at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:552:15)

at TLSSocket.Socket.\_onTimeout (node:net:550:8)

at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)

at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

the part of my code for connecting to redis instance is as below

```
        const REDISHOST = process.env.REDISHOST;
        const REDISPORT = process.env.REDISPORT;
        const REDISAUTH = process.env.AUTHSTRING;
        const REDISKEY = process.env.REDISKEY;

        const client = redis.createClient({
            host: REDISHOST,
            port: REDISPORT,
            password: REDISAUTH,
             tls: {
                ca: REDISKEY
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: i have tried adding connectTimeout: 10000 but still does not work

Comment: Are all of your environment variables set? If host and port and undefined, Redis will default to localhostL:6379. In a cloud function context, this would certainly give you a timeout as there ain't no Redis there.